# Wordpress exclude duplicated $sticky post from loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

Since Wordpress [sticky posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts) feature allow the post checked as *sticky* in post publish panel to be placed at the top of the front page of posts. I was also intended to style the sticky post differently than normal ones within the loop by customizing [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) default coding as following:

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php $post = $posts[0]; $c=0;?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

     <?php $c++;
       if( is_home() && !$paged && $c == 1 ) :?>
         <!--First sticky post content -->

    <?php elseif( is_home() && !$paged && $c == 2 ) :?>
        <!--Second sticky post content -->

    <?php elseif( is_home() && !$paged && $c == 3 ) :?>
        <!--Third sticky post content -->

    <?php else:?>
        <!-- Standard post content -->

    <?php endif;?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- End of the main loop -->
      //pagination

    <?php else : ?>
      <?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

The result is I get the first three posts (checked as sticky) with customized style while duplicated within **standard posts** output in which I failed to get rid of.

I tried to replace `<?php else : ?>` with `<?php elseif(!is_sticky()) : ?>` but that made page being displayed is "paged" or has current page number is greater than one has posts count subtracted by sticky posts according to publish date per each page.

Any help to make sticky posts not duplicated is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have 2 loops or just 1? Kindly share the whole code if possible...

Comment: Hey @Ehab, Assuming you have only one loop, Check out my answer below 

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you to read the WP_Query documentation:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters

You can create new (or alter existing) query and fetch posts without the sticky ones.

> **Don't Show Sticky Posts**
>
> Exclude all sticky posts from the query:
>
> `$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) ) );`

I suggest that you make 2 consecutive queries.

First one to fetch the sticky posts and the second one to fetch all other posts (sticky one excluded, as described above).

Comment: I am familiar with query arguments. That will completely remove sticky posts from the whole loop while I need them only on first page https://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts

Comment: In that case, I suggest you use two loops, first one to get the sticky posts, and the second one to get all the other posts (sticky ones excluded).

Answer (score 2):

To handle sticky posts do

```
<?php
    $sticky_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) ) );
    while ($sticky_query->have_posts()) : $sticky_query->the_post();
?>
```

To handle posts which are not sticky do

```
<?php
    $non_sticky_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) ) ); 
    while ($non_sticky_query->have_posts()) : $non_sticky_query->the_post();
?>
```

PS - `is_sticky()` won't work here as I'm guessing this code runs on your home page. `is_sticky()` will require the `post_id` to work as required on pages other than the post page.

You can do something like this `is_sticky(get_the_ID())` inside the loop in your current code.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate home-page posts and other posts like that:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

<!-- if home page -->
<?php if( is_home() && !$paged ) :?>

  <!-- First page loop -->
  <?php $post = $posts[0]; $c=0;?>
  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

     <?php $c++;
     if( $c == 1 ) { ?>
     <!--First sticky post content -->
     <?php } ?>

     <?php if( $c == 2 ) { ?>
     <!--Second sticky post content -->
     <?php } ?>

     <?php if( $c == 3 ) { ?>
     <!--Third sticky post content -->
     <?php } ?>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <!-- End of first page loop -->

<!-- else if not home page -->
<?php else:?>

  <!-- exclude stuicky posts, then run the standard loop -->
  <?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) ) );

  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <!-- Standard post content -->

  <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif;?>
<!-- end if home page / else -->
  //pagination

<!-- else if have no posts -->
<?php else : ?>
  <?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
<!-- end if have posts / else -->
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code to display only sticky posts

```
<?php
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 4,
'post__in'  => get_option('sticky_posts'), //that will display only sticky posts
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
while($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
?>
    <!-- sticky posts -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

then use this code to remove only sticky posts from the loop

```
<?php
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 4,
'post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts') //that will remove only sticky posts
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
while($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
?>
    <!-- normal posts content without sticky -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `continue` in `else` if post is sticky

Put

```
<?php if ( is_sticky() ) continue;?>
```

on the top of else section...
You code will look something like this

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $post = $posts[0]; $c=0;?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

 <?php $c++;
   if( is_home() && !$paged && $c == 1 ) :?>
     <!--First sticky post content -->

<?php elseif( is_home() && !$paged && $c == 2 ) :?>
    <!--Second sticky post content -->

<?php elseif( is_home() && !$paged && $c == 3 ) :?>
    <!--Third sticky post content -->

<?php else:?>
    <?php if ( is_sticky() ) continue;?>
    <!-- Standard post content -->

<?php endif;?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<!-- End of the main loop -->
  //pagination

<?php else : ?>
  <?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```